# getting pyreverse not to produce blank output files (eg PDF or png is blank)

Tags: python, pyreverse

Whenever I follow the pyreverse guides and attempt
To generate a UML diagram for my filename.py, I get a blank png file or blank PDF file, depending on which output file type I pick. Has someone experienced this? Can you help me sort this out?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you expand on your question by providing code examples for what you are currently trying? Currently it is not clear how anybody could reproduce your problem. Also consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and reading the [how do I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: I have solved this issue. I realised I did not install the module for which I could see the python source code in spyder and wanted to generate a UML diagram for. Once I performed an python setup.py install for that module and then tried the same pyreverse command line call, I was able to obtain a png/PDF showing the UML diagram.